# Error al intentar subir una aplicación a play store

Tags: android, google-play-console

Quisiera ayuda sobre el siguiente tema que me tiene ya 2 veces rindiendo ya que no encuentro la solución, quiero subir una APK a play store la cuál tiene la siguiente línea de código:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="cesarruiz.cflowmovil.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
```

---

Cuando la quiero subir me sale lo siguiente: "Subiste un APK o Android App Bundle que especifica un documento de esquema de acciones en el archivo de manifiesto, pero todavía no se permiten esquemas de acciones"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje que indicas:

> Subiste un APK o Android App Bundle que especifica un documento de
>   esquema de acciones en el archivo de manifiesto, pero todavía no se
>   permiten esquemas de acciones

se muestra también en idioma inglés de esta forma :

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which specifies an actions
>   schema document in its manifest, but action schemas are not yet
>   allowed. If you are part of a beta program, you need to have your
>   developer account whitelisted.

El problema aquí es lo que la definición de `actions`, si eliminas esta sección debe funcionar sin problema:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.actions"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
```

El uso de [Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments) aún es Beta

https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments

Comment: Muchísimas gracias con la respuesta, funcionó correctamente

Comment: @CésarAndrésRuizSaltos un placer ayudar,saludos!